# Nginx rejects custom HTTP Methods if not all upper-case

Tags: http, nginx

If the HTTP Method is not all upper-case, Nginx rejects the request and sends a 400 response along with its internal 400 HTML error page.

no details shown on "error_log info"

example: Link, LInK, SeaRCH, VeRB, etc ... upper-case versions of those work, its jut the mixed case.

Comment: UPDATE: as @JulianReschke pointed out, the proper response should be 501 not 400, Nginx is doing something weird, further more, the Allow header I'm sending is upper cased so I shall try with a mixed case and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Note: I discovered this problem because of a [related issue in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649972/firefox-overwrites-custom-http-method-link-to-mixed-case-link-on-xhr)

Comment: also, interesting enough, tried this with Apache, and it doesn't mind the mixed case ... but Apache sucks, so no wonder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1);

> The Method token indicates the method to be performed on the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI. ***The method is case-sensitive***.

As far as I can tell, Nginx is doing the right thing according to the specification. If you disagree, you'll have to explain what you think it's doing wrong more clearly.

Edit: Yes, I agree with the answer from @JulianReschke, it should return a 501 status code, not a 400, good catch.

Comment: you are correct, in that Nginx is rightfully rejecting the request, and @JulianReschke is correct in that it should return a 501. I do not expect it to succeed, I just want to know why its returning a 400.

Comment: I shall also try sending the mixed case version in my "Allow" header and see if Nginx passes those through ... though I'm still intrigued about the 400 and where its coming from.

Answer (score 2):

The response code should be 501. Otherwise: works as defined, no?

Comment: correct, it should be, so the question becomes why is it returning a 400? I can't seem to find any config option to help with that.