# Firefox overwrites custom HTTP Method "LINK" to mixed-case "Link" on XHR

Tags: http, firefox

Firefox seems to be forcing the HTTP Method: "LINK" in particular to "Link" on XHR requests

I've tried a number of other custom HTTP Methods, such as "SEARCH", "TAG", etc .. and they seem to work fine.

its just this one method, Firefox seems to be messing with.

Comment: Same applies to "ACCEPT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477578

Comment: Aha, so I'm not crazy after all, and this is a known FireFox bug. thx!

Comment: Just FYI: It helps pushing people. I just wrote a comment to get the bug report up on the latest-changed view and @mcmanus picket it up and fixed it - finally!!